# Автозаполнение в QLineEdit с текстом на фоне

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlineedit

Мой проект - аналог таких проектов, как [Wox](https://github.com/Wox-launcher/Wox/releases), [ueli](https://github.com/oliverschwendener/ueli/releases) и [PowerToys Run](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/), которые в свою очередь аналоги [Spotlight](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)) - функциональный поисковик в *Mac OS*.
Я пишу свой проект исключительно на *PyQt5* и на данный момент моя задача - реализовать автозаполнение введенного пользователем текста по нажатию на `Tab` или стрелку вправо. Да, в *PyQt5* есть класс `QCompleter`, созданный как раз для таких целей, но давайте взглянем на то, как это реализовано, например, в *PowerToys Run*:

[image: автозаполнение в PowerToys Run]

А вот, как автозаполнение будет выглядеть в *PyQt5* с использованием `QCompleter`:

[image: автозаполнение в PyQt5 с помощью QCompleter]

Т.е. вместо того, чтобы сделать текст как бы на фоне, как `placeholder`, `QCompleter` вставляет текст и выделяет его, оставляя курсор на месте. Примерно так выглядит мой код:

```
lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
strList = ['telegram', 'PyCharm', 'Yandex', 'Minecraft']
completer = QCompleter(strList, lineEdit)
lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)
```

Мне же нужно сделать как в первом случае. У меня есть 2 потенциально возможных варианта решения:

1. Поиграться с `PlaceholderText`. Возможно есть способ не убирать его, когда пользователь вводит текст. Тогда текст после введенного пользователем текста будет "в фоне"
2. Возможно такого результата можно добиться с помощью `setStyleSheet()`, но я не уверен, что средствами css это можно сделать

Буду рад любым советам и идеям!

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно ли я вас понял, но как вариант предложу попробовать:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Completer(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Completer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion) 
        self._le = args[-1]
        self._path = ''
        self._path_2 = ''
        self._all_path = ''
        self.lbl = QLabel(self._le)
        self.lbl.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                font-family:'Consolas'; 
                color: #777;   
                font: 25px;
                background-color: #2b2b2b;
            }
        """)
        self.lbl.hide()
        
    def pathFromIndex(self, index):   
        rect = QRect(
            self._le.cursorRect().x(),
            self._le.cursorRect().y(),
            self._le.width(),
            self._le.completer().widget().height()
        ) 
        self.lbl.move(self._le.cursorRect().x()+8, self._le.cursorRect().y())
        self.lbl.setText(index.data()[len(self._path_2):])
        self.lbl.adjustSize()
        self.lbl.show()
       
        self._all_path = index.data()
        return self._path

    def splitPath(self, path):
        self._path = self._le.text() 
        self._path_2 = path
        return [path]


class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()  
        self._all_text = ''        
        self.multipleCompleter = None

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        
        if not self.multipleCompleter:
            return
        c = self.multipleCompleter
        
        if self.text() == "": 
            return
        c.setCompletionPrefix(self.cursorWord(self.text()))      
        
        if len(c.completionPrefix()) < 1:
            c.popup().hide()
            return
        c.complete()

    def cursorWord(self, sentence):
        p = sentence.rfind(" ")
        if p == -1:
            return sentence
        return sentence[p + 1:]

    def insertCompletion(self, text):
        p = self.text().rfind(" ")                                
        text = self.multipleCompleter._all_path
         
        if p == -1:
            pass
        else:
            text = self.text()[:p+1] + self.multipleCompleter._all_path
            
        self.multipleCompleter.lbl.hide()
        QTimer.singleShot(10, lambda: self.allText(text))

    def allText(self, text):
        self.setText(text)
        self._all_text = text
        self.setFocus()
        self.update()

    def event(self, event):
        if self.multipleCompleter:
            if self.multipleCompleter.popup().currentIndex().row() == -1:
                self.multipleCompleter.lbl.hide()
            else:    
                if not self.multipleCompleter.popup().selectedIndexes():
                    # self.multipleCompleter.popup().hide()
                    self.multipleCompleter.lbl.hide()
                    QTimer.singleShot(10, lambda: self.allText(self.multipleCompleter._path))
        return super().event(event)

    def setMultipleCompleter(self, completer):
        self.multipleCompleter = completer
        self.multipleCompleter.setWidget(self)
        completer.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = LineEdit()        
    editor.setStyleSheet("""
        LineEdit {
            font-family:'Consolas'; 
            color: #fff;
            font: 25px;
            background-color: #2b2b2b;
        }
    """)
     
    strList = [ 
        'def', 'Python', 'PyQt5', 'Qt', 'Django', 'QML',
        'matthew','mark','morris','mickey',
        'the', 'function', 'get_request', 'returns', 'list', 
        'of', 'names', 'taken', 'from', '112233', 
        'telegram', 'PyCharm', 'Yandex', 'Minecraft',
        'telegram-2', 'PyQt6', 'Yandex-2', 'Minecraft-2',                  
    ]
    completer = Completer(strList, editor)  
    editor.setCompleter(completer)
    completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)  # без учета регистра
    editor.setMultipleCompleter(completer)
    editor.show()
    editor.resize(670, 70)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, это действительно то, что мне нужно. Почти. Не подскажите, как убрать попап-меню и сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на `tab` вставлялся текст из `Completer` в конец текста. Я пробовал отловить клавишу `tab` через `keyPressEvent()`, но все безуспешно

Comment: @MotoDev я не совсем понимаю, что у вас не так, потому что у меня все работает именно так, как вы описали, т.е. по нажатию на  `tab`  текст из `Completer` вставляется  в конец текста `lineEdit`, а `popup` меню закрывается.

Comment: @MotoDev есть ли у вас разница в выполняемых действиях когда вы нажимаете `tab`  и когда вы нажимаете `Enter` ?